# Benefits or Disadvantages of .NET Design Pattern for abstract/virtual OnMethod

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I've noticed in a lot of Microsoft .NET classes that there's often a non-abstract/virtual public method, such as

```
public bool MyAwesomeMethod(object someParameter);
```

And a protected abstract/virtual method such as

```
protected virtual bool OnMyAwesomeMethod(object someParameter);
```

I recently started to wonder whether this was a known design pattern or not and what the advantages and disadvantages of such a design might be. Is it all about enabling the base class to execute some logic that children of the class can't prevent (such as logging)? Is it undesirable for some reason to use this sort design by default for methods you know you want to be overridable in child classes? Are there other considerations I'm not picking up on?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much it; you use it when you want some behaviour to always happen before and/or after the derived classes' override.

Logging is certainly possible, but unlikely in the more low-level calls that it is sometimes done with. It could be one of several things though, which might be vital to the class' operation.

It could also be done "just in case" such trapping of each call before or after is needed later. Normal flexibility vs YAGNI arguments apply.

Answer (score 1):

In MS WinForms/WPF coding convention, a function beginning with "On" is used to raise an event. These methods sometimes, but not always, have related public methods; they almost always have related event delegates.

The advantages (and disadvantages) of this have to do with separation of concerns, and the message passing inherent in the Windows GUI. Basically, when you call a method, say Control.Invalidate(), what you are doing is telling the control to send a message to itself through the Windows message loop (in this case the WM_PAINT message). That is pushed out by the program to Windows, which then puts it on the back end of the message queue for the application to deal with. In this way, commands involving the UI are handled in a FIFO manner, and things like animations or constant changes to the UI don't take up all the UI thread's time.

Anyway, when the message pump for the program gets the WM_PAINT message back out of the queue, it directs it to the control, which responds to it by calling OnPaint(). OnPaint() does the basic control drawing (by calling other methods, usually), and then raises the Paint event, to which other pieces of code may be listening because they should do something when the control is repainted.